# Cannot copy ArrayList while trying to make a copy of original ArrayList for SearchView

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, searchview

I am trying to build a SearchView for my app and while following "CodingInFLow"'s tutorial on YouTube, he said to create a copy of your original ArrayList that will contain all the items. I followed the tutorial thorouhghly and did everything similarly with my app. But when I write "mUploadsSearch = new ArrayList<>(uploads)" it doesn't store any data and my app doesn't return any data on SearchView. If I writre "mUploadsSearch = uploads", it does work and filter the contents but only once for the first search.

Here is my code for my ImageAdapter :

```
public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ImageViewHolder> implements 
Filterable {
private Context mContext;
private List<Upload> mUploads;
private List<Upload> mUploadsSearch;

private OnItemClickListener mListener;
public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<Upload> uploads) {
    mContext = context;
    mUploads = uploads;
    mUploadsSearch = new ArrayList<Upload>();
    mUploadsSearch.addAll(uploads);
}
@Override
public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.image_item, parent, false);
    return new ImageViewHolder(v);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Upload uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(position);
    holder.textViewName.setText(uploadCurrent.getName());
    Picasso.get()
            .load(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_food)
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(holder.imageView);
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mUploads.size();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return filter;
}
private Filter filter = new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
        List<Upload> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (charSequence == null || charSequence.length() == 0) {
            filteredList.addAll(mUploadsSearch);
        } else {
            String filterPattern = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
            for (Upload item : mUploadsSearch) {
                if (item.getName().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                    filteredList.add(item);
                }
            }
        }

        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        results.values = filteredList;
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults results) {
        mUploads.clear();
        mUploads.addAll((Collection<? extends Upload>) results.values);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};

public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
//        View.OnCreateContextMenuListener, MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener
{
    public TextView textViewName;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_upload);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        //itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                mListener.onItemClick(position);
            }
        }
    }
}
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position);
    //void onWhatEverClick(int position);
    //void onDeleteClick(int position);
}
public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}
```

}

Sorry for any mistakes made, I am entirely new to Programming and would appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Hello Paul

Use **this** : this.mUploadsSearch = new ArrayList<Upload>();

[Java this keyword](https://www.guru99.com/java-this-keyword.html)

Comment: @DaltonDias Hey Dalton, thanks for commenting and helping me out, but I don't quite understand how that would have in copying the original arrayList's data to mUploadsSearch.